# How could I avoid using a MySQL query in a While loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that outputs a list of classes. In the classes database the teacher name is determined by the teachers ID in the users database.

Here is my database structure.

```
Classes Database
-----------------------------
ID       CLASS              TEACHER
1        product design     3

User Database
-----------------------------
ID       NAME
3        John Doe
```

So when listing my classes I need it to convert "3" into "John Doe".

This is my current code:

```
<?php 
  $classdetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class");
  while($class = mysql_fetch_array($classdetails)) {
    $marklist_class = $class['class'];
    $marklist_teacher = $class['teacher']; //This is a userid                                   

    //------Somewhere here i need to get the userid and look it up in the user database
    if($marklist_class=="") {

    } else {
      echo $marklist_class . ' ' . $marklist_teacher;}
    }
  }
?>
```

I understand just putting another mysql query there will lower performance and is not advised, so how would I look up the user database for every row without adding a query into the while loop.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like you need to pull more information in with your initial query, unless it's hierarchical data; then I'd say make 2 queries at the beginning, toss them into arrays, and reference both in your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a join query to get all the info that you need at once. Then in your application you can sort through it and display accordingly.
e.g.

```
SELECT Classes.class, Users.Name
FROM Classes JOIN Users on Classes.Teacher = Users.ID
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked, Is this possible to do with three or more tables tables?

Comment: You can join as many tables as you want, as long as they relate to each other in some way, just add a new join after the previous. Make sure that you pull them in order, though - the join you're typing should join with information pulled in the initial query or a previous join.

Comment: Yes, I have got it working, took a while to get my head around thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM class c JOIN user u ON u.ID = c.TEACHER
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JOIN in your initial query.

```
Select c.id, c.class, c.teacher, u.name from class c join user u on u.id = c.teacher
```

this will return all the columns from Class, plus the matched teacher name column from User, all in one query.